# Distinct Last By

Tags: scala, collections

I am searching for a solution with good performance of the following `distinctLastBy` method:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
implicit final class SeqPimp[A, S[A] <: Seq[A]](val s: S[A]) extends AnyVal {
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
  private final def build[B](build: Builder[B, S[B]] => Unit)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], B, S[B]]): S[B] = {
    val b = cbf()
    build(b)
    b.result
  }
  final def distinctBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], A, S[A]]): S[A] = {
    build[A] { builder =>
      val seen = scala.collection.mutable.Set[B]()
      for (a <- s; b = f(a); if !(seen contains b)) {
        seen += b
        builder += a
      }
    }
  }
  final def distinctLastBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], A, S[A]]): S[A] = {
    // instead of keeping the first occurence of an element the last one will be kept
    build[A] { builder => builder ++= s.view.reverse.distinctBy(f).reverse }
  }
}
```

An example:

```
case class Num(integralDigits: Int, fractionalDigits: Int)
val nums = Num(2, 11) :: Num(1, 23) :: Num(1, 45) :: Num(3, 11) :: Num(2, 22) :: Nil
nums distinctLastBy (_.integralDigits) // List(Num(1,45), Num(3,11), Num(2,22))
```

It would be nice to have the result elements sorted by first occurence (of the `by`-argument) in the original list.

```
List(Num(2,22), Num(1,45), Num(3,11))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targetting the JVM, what about something based on `java.util.LinkedHashMap`?

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

final def distinctLastBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], A, S[A]]): S[A] = {
  build[A] { builder =>
    val map = new LinkedHashMap[B, A]
    for (a <- s; b = f(a)) {
      map(b) = a
    }
    builder ++= map.values
  }
}
```

LinkedHashMap keeps track of the insertion order in a LinkedList. Of course, we can do the same ourselves in pure Scala:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

final class Ref[A](var x: A)

final def pureDistinctLastBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], A, S[A]]): S[A] = {
  build[A] { builder =>
    var seen = Map.empty[B, Ref[A]]
    val listBuf = ListBuffer.empty[Ref[A]]
    for (a <- s; b = f(a)) {
      seen.get(b) match {
        case Some(ref) => ref.x = a
        case None =>
          val ref = new Ref(a)
          seen += b -> ref
          listBuf += ref
      }
    }
    builder ++= listBuf.view.map(_.x)
  }
}
```

The `Ref`s save us having to search the list when updating it with new information. Those `Ref`s will upset any functional programming enthusiasts, so we can instead use the `Map` `seen` to keep track of the positions of the items in the list, rather than storing references to them:

```
final def functionalDistinctLastBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], A, S[A]]): S[A] = {
  build[A] { builder =>
    val (seen, list) = ((Map.empty[B, Int], IndexedSeq.empty[A]) /: s){(acc, a) =>
      val (innerSeen, innerList) = acc
      val b = f(a)
      innerSeen.get(b) match {
        case Some(i) => (innerSeen, innerList.updated(i, a))
        case None => (innerSeen + (b -> innerList.size), innerList :+ a)
      }
    }
    builder ++= list
  }
}
```

Although I suspect it won't be quite as fast as the imperative version.

Comment: Thank you very very much. This is a great answer. I like the `Ref`s. Even functional enthusiasts have to accept that in a hybrid language like scala `var`s within a manageable scope (you can declare the `Ref`-class within `pureDistinctLastBy`) are acceptable to gain the needed performance. In addition I like the different views to the distinctLastBy subject.

Comment: In case you have already tested the performance especially on `distinctLastBy` versus `pureDistinctLastBy`, let me know!

Comment: I haven't benchmarked them, but I know that the functional version will be O(n log(n)) (because the default immutable implementations of Map and IndexedSeq are O(log n)), whereas the mutable versions version will both be O(n) (as long as you're using mutable.Map in the Scala version). Of course, the usual caveats about premature optimisation apply - gzm0's answer is much simpler than mine, and may well be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep an implementation using a builder, I can only confirm @James_pic's answer. Consider using a `SortedMap` if you want your keys to be sorted in the end.

Another, more code-lightweight possibility is:

```
nums.groupBy(_.integralDigits).map(_._2.last)
```

Comment: Thanks! Lightweight, indeed! But I doubt that it meets my performance requirement. But this should be tested!

Comment: Probably creating a `List` for each integral digit kills the performance. IMHO Scala should have a `foldBy` on the std. library.